# How do you address variable names where the name inherently begins with a number?

Tags: vb.net, naming-conventions

Part of the challenge of writing maintainable code is a good naming convention.  But sometimes a good, meaningful name involves a number being at the at the start of the variable.  For example, take a 401k.  Theres not another name in which to call it, and the literal spelling of it is kind of tacky (`FourOhOneK`).

```
Public Enum AccountType
    Savings = 0
    Checking = 1
    Certificate = 2
    FourOhOneK = 3  'The odd one out
    '_401k?
    'n401k?
    'Four01k?
    'etc
End Enum
```

I *can* most certainly make my own obscurities for names, but I will and whoever maintains my code more than likely get tripped up on it one day.  My question is, **are there any conventions within the programming community that addresses this, or is this left up to the individual programmer/policies of the company that dictate this?**

Comment: No, picking good names is a programmer's job and should use the guidelines established by the team.  Knowing the domain before you start programming is half the battle.  "RetirementPlan" jumps to mind.

Comment: If you think there is no other name to call a "401K" then you need to step back and think a bit more generically! If you left the US you'd probably find not many people have even heard of a 401K let alone knowing what it is. Think about what it IS, not what people call it.

Comment: @AAT Great way to look at it.  An abstraction of what it IS can be very helpful in deciding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specific to your example, one could use the word Retirement:

```
public Enum AccountType
  Savings = 0
  .
  .
  .
  Education529
  Retirement401k
  RetirementIRA
  RetirementRothIRA
  etc
End Enum
```

Of course, that doesn't really answer the general question, but maybe you will find it useful.

As a pattern, or convention, one could prepend the domain-specific number with a domain-specific qualifier.